# How to parallelize a shell script that reads lines of a text file as input?

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script that reads lines of a text file and uses each line as an argument for a python script.

```
file="some_file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    python some_script.py "$line"
done <"$file"
```

It takes a few minutes for `some_script.py` to finish processing one line and there are more than 10000 lines in the text file. So in total I need to wait for a long time before the shell script finishes.

How to do this in parallel? e.g. executing 10 `python some_script.py $line` simultaneously, which can reduce the total execution time by 90%.

Comment: Are you sure you want `$line` vs `"$line"`? This means that a `*` in your text will be replaced with a list of files in the current directory, for example.

Comment: (btw, while Python is fairly quick to start up, it'd still be lower overhead to do this from inside the Python interpreter so that individual processes are `fork()`ed off without needing an `exec()` [and thus to spin up that `exec`'d interpreter from scratch -- re-loading/parsing the modules &c]; the multiprocessing module has some relevant tools).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
1. Yes, I should use `"$line"` to avoid potential problems;

2. doing multiprocessing is indeed an option, but the Python script is still under development and I don't want to introduce some more complexity into that, so I decided to do that using shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash (for the `$'\n'` syntax) and GNU xargs (for the `-d` and `-P` arguments):

```
# runs one python process per line, with whole line passed as an argument
<"$file" xargs -d $'\n' -P10 -n1 python some_script.py
```

One caveat is that this will pass each line to your Python script as a single argument. If you need the shell to perform string-splitting first:

```
# string-splits and glob-expands each line into a list of arguments
# reuses each "sh" instance for as many arguments as possible
<"$file" xargs -d $'\n' -P10 sh -c 'for arg; do python some_script.py $arg; done'
```

Comment: The manual of `xargs` says `xargs` is delimited by newlines by default, so why do you explicitly use `-d $'\n'`?

Comment: `cat some_file.txt | xargs -P10 -n1 python some_script.py` works for me, is it equivalent to using `<"$file" xargs -d $'\n' -P10 -n1 python some_script.py`?

Comment: @ChengxinMa, you're misreading the manual. By default, xargs is delimited by not just newlines, but also tabs and spaces. It also attempts to honor quotes rather than treating them as literal data. As such, these are *not* identical invocations.

Comment: Compare `printf '%s\n' "hello \"cruel world\"" "goodbye \"cruel world\"" | xargs printf '<%s>\n'` to the same with `xargs -d $'\n'` to see the differences in action.

Comment: (BTW, as an aside, `cat some_file | ...` is less efficient than `<some_file ...`, as it requires your program to read from a FIFO to `/usr/bin/cat`, rather than giving it a handle letting it read direct from the input file; that's particularly true for programs like `sort`, which can parallelize their reads when given a real file handle, whereas a FIFO can only be read once front-to-back; no seeking, no rereading, etc).

Answer (score 2):

```
let x=10
while IFS= read -r line; do
   python some_script.py $line &
   let x=x-1 || { wait; let x=10; }
done <$file
wait
```

Comment: The OP was correct to quote `<"$file"` -- depending on the name, it's possible to get an "ambiguous redirect" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

With **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel -a some_file.txt -j 10 python some_script.py
```

You can add progress bars with `--progress` and change the number of parallel jobs with `-j N`. You can also tag output lines with the program name using `--tag` and get an estimated time of arrival with `--eta`. You can also distribute the jobs over multiple hosts quite simply and change the behaviour if any job fails.

Finally, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

to see exactly what it would do without actually doing anything.

So, if `args.txt` looks like this;

```
first line of arguments
line 2 arguments
this the the third set
```

You can do this:

```
parallel -a args.txt --colsep ' ' echo someScript.py

somescript.py line 2 arguments
somescript.py first line of arguments
somescript.py this the the third set
```

Comment: This requires installing `parallel` and even after that the command doesn't work. In the manual page it only says `-a` is used to specify the input file. I doubt if it can automatically use each line of the input file as the argument to the python script.

Comment: That is exactly how it works. I have updated the answer - please check again.

Comment: The echo example also works for me, but when executing the Python script I somehow got such an error: `IndexError: list index out of range` in some line in the Python script. (Besides, the `parallel` program asks me to cite it when I publish my work. I am afraid I will forget it in the end so I am not gonna use it unless other solutions doesn't work.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `--colsep`. You only need to acknowledge the citation one time.